# jQuery append DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

All the examples of jQuery.append() seem to take an html string and append it to a container. I have a slightly different use case. My server returns me an XML that contains HTML text to be displayed, something like:

```
<event source="foo">
    <contents>
        <h1>This is an event</h1>
        This is the body of the event
    </contents>
</event>
```

I have a div where this content needs to be displayed.

My JS currently does the following:

1. Loads up the XML data into jQuery in the $.ajax() success handler:

   var jData = $( data );
2. Find the contents tag and tries to add its children to the div that is supposed to display the event:

   ```
   var contents = jData.find( "contents" );
   if( contents != null )
   {
       $( contents ).children().each( function( index, value ) 
       {
        $( "#eventDiv" ).append( $( value ) );
       });
   }
   ```

The append() call fails with **Uncaught Error: WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: DOM Exception 4** on Chrome. The debugger shows value to be a DOM *Element* object and *$( value )* to be an *Object* that contains the *Element*.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.
-Raj

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't append nodes that belong to one DOM tree to another document.

Try to [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) them:

```
$("#eventDiv").append( jData.find("contents").children().clone() );
```

or simply use their textual representation to have them re-created:

```
$("#eventDiv").append( jData.find("contents").html() );
```

Comment: Thanks. Clone() seems to move me forward. Still, calling html() causes error: $( child ).clone().html(): TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined

Comment: actually I use contents().clone() which also includes text nodes.

Comment: @raj: The `.html()` fails because you are dealing with an XML document here, and jQuery is not 100% fitted to deal with XML in all cases.

Comment: I am much futher along. The problem I face now is warrants a new question. Thanks for your help, Tomalak!

Comment: @raj: You're welcome. If you have a chance to change how the server sends the response, just XML-encode everything within `<contents>` and do `$("#eventDiv").append( jData.find("contents").text() );`.

Comment: I faced this problem when trying to append some DOM nodes from one document to an iframe. clone() solved the problem but not for IE6/IE7. Tried html() and this works for all browsers.