# jQuery DOM append losing markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

This is related to an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679114/jquery-append-dom). I try to append HTML DOM returned in an AJAX response to an existing DIV. I see all the text, but it seems all markup such as bold, italic, etc is lost.

My AJAX (XML) data is like so:

```
<event source="foo">
    <contents>
        <h1>This is an event</h1>
        This is the body of the event
    </contents>
</event>
```

My jQuery code does this:

```
$("#eventDiv").append( jData.find("contents").contents().clone() );
```

Attempting to do .html() on the cloned contents throws an exception: **TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined**.

I am a little surprised that it is so excruciatingly hard to do this with jQuery. Am I doing something too far off the track?

Comment: can you post some HTML and your jQuery AJAX call?

Comment: Need to see more of your AJAX code.  Do you run ajaxSetup()?  What type are you getting back?  What's in jData?

Comment: I had to resort to XMLSerializer. I iterate over each child and use the serializer to convert it to text before appending. Lesson learnt: Currently jQuery.append() will not work with DOM objects if they are takes from XMLHTTP response.

Comment: @hunter, peter: please see referenced earlier question for that info. I finally found a solution, but do not like it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the trouble is for jQuery to find tags/nodes which are named different from allowed tags. That said, your XML is not well formatted either as it has both a node and text within contents.

This is not nice, but it will work:

```
$("#eventDiv").append($(":first-child", data).parent().html());
```

The `<content>` tag will be included, but is ignored by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like jQuery does not provide an easy way for what I am trying to do. To recap, my server returns the following data in ajax response:

```
<event source="foo">
    <contents>
        <h1>This is an event</h1>
        This is the body of the event
    </contents>
</event>
```

I would like to display the stuff inside the *contents* tag in a div.
My JS code handles this in the ajax success handler as follows:

```
var jData = $( data );
```

I have a div with id *eventDiv* where I need to display the contents of the event. I was hoping to do it with:

```
$("#eventDiv").append( jData.find("contents").contents().clone() );
```

but this was causing all markup to be lost, resulting in just the text.

The following based on XMLSerializer works for me (will not work for IE):

```
var contents = jData.find( "contents" );

if( contents != null )
{
    var serializer = new XMLSerializer ();
    $( contents ).contents().each( function( index, value ) 
    {
        var cloned = $( value ).clone();
        $( "#eventDiv" ).append( serializer.serializeToString( cloned[ 0 ] ) );
    });
}
```